# Make the "Next privilege" bar chart relative to the last

Tags: discussion

Just an idea, but the "Next privilege" always looks like you've nearly attained it:

[image: Next Privilege]

Because I have 2112 rep, I'm assuming the bar is 84.48% of the way along - that's how close I am to my next privilege based on overall rep between 0 and 2500.

Personally, I'd like to see it based upon the last thing I attained. So, the last privilege was editing posts at 2,000 and the next is creating tag synonyms at 2,500.

IMHO I'm less than half way towards the next priviledge, I need 500 additional rep from the last one and I have 112, so I think this bar should be just 22.4% of the way along.

In other words, restart the bar from the beginning once I gain a new privilege. I think that way I'd see it raising a bit quicker, and the overall length of the bar would be 500 points and not 2500 points, so I'd see progress a bit easier.

Sorry if I haven't explained it very well.

Answer (score 1):

It is displayed that way so that users have a consistent idea of how much reputation they need to gain to get the next privilege. If it was to change to only show how much more you need to gain then the scale of the bar graph would be changing with every privilege which would be very confusing.

here is a partial list that should show how quickly it would become confusing if it changed the scale for each privilege.

> 1->5       - 4
>   5->10      - 5
>   10->15     - 5
>   15->20     - 5
>   20->50     - 30
>   50->75     - 25
>   75->100    - 25
>   100->125   - 25
>   125->200   - 75
>   200->250   - 50
>   250->500   - 250
>   500->1000  - 500

Comment: Now, marking the rep for the last privilige gained, that might be a useful idea...